# JavaScript Conceptual Issue with a code. Please give an explanation for the output i am getting

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, ecmascript-6, es6-promise

I am having difficulty in understanding the following code, i have put a comment where i do not understand the concept, what exactly is going on

```
var ob = {};
var ob2 = ['name'];
for(var op of ob2)
{
      ob[op]='at'; // here i dont understand what is happening, why here is an array type brackets

}
console.log(ob);

OUTPUT IS


name:'at'
```

Comment: [JavaScript object basics - Learn web development | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Basics)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript property access: dot notation vs. brackets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4968406/javascript-property-access-dot-notation-vs-brackets)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to access object properties in JavaScript

```
var person = {
  name: 'Jane'
}

person.name
// or
person['name'] 
// both return jane
```

in your case, that iterates through members of the array called `ob2`
first and only element of that array is a string `name` and it's given to that object as a prop, which becomes like following

```
ob['name'] = 'at';
// or
ob.name = 'at';
```

When to use brackets([]) over dot(.)
If you don't know the prop name at runtime you need to go with brackets, if you do know it you can choose either dot notation or brackets

Answer (score 1):

That is just the syntax for accessing or assigning properties of an object dynamically in javascript.

You can think of it as though you are doing: `ob.name = 'at'`.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, it's accessing a property of the object `ob`.  In this case, is accessing and creating new properties.

The loop is getting each index value, and for each assign/create a new property using that index value.

That approach is a dynamically way of creating property-names in an object.

```
ob['name'] = 'at';
ob.name = 'at'; // Just to illustrate
```

Read a little the docs here `->` [JavaScript object basics - Learn web development | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Objects/Basics)